# Unable to install an application via Wine that requires .Net4

Tags: wine, 32-bit, dotnet

I'm trying to install the trial of this application in a wineprefix 32bit:
https://www.dextronet.com/swift-to-do-list-software

It request dotnet 4, it is included in the installer in case it is not detected on the system.

When I start the application, error with crash log occour.

Installed:
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFw7H.png)

Error:
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55tDf.png)

System Info:

```
uname -a
Linux marco-N56VZ 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

System Info

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

System info at the end of the log:

```
System information:
    Wine build: wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.19.0-35-generic
```

Log:

```
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:006b GS:0063
 EIP:7b010be6 ESP:01bae8d4 EBP:01bae948 EFLAGS:00000246(   - --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:01bae8e0 EBX:00000000 ECX:00000010 EDX:01bae9b0
 ESI:e0434352 EDI:019e2250
Stack dump:
0x01bae8d4:  00000000 00000000 01baf5b8 e0434352
0x01bae8e4:  00000001 00000000 7b010be6 00000005
0x01bae8f4:  80070057 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x01bae904:  79140000 7919c5d4 00000059 00000000
0x01bae914:  01bae9b0 02cf24b0 02000059 01bae930
0x01bae924:  79150579 01bae938 02000059 01bae93c
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b010be6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in kernelbase (0x01bae948)
  1 0x791cac08 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in clr (0x01bae9e4)
  2 0x791cae41 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in clr (0x01baeaa4)
  3 0x094c9920 (0x01baeab0)
  4 0x094c8af2 (0x01baeac8)
  5 0x094c98ce (0x01baeae8)
  6 0x0954a54a (0x01baeb0c)
  7 0x09540867 (0x01baed8c)
  8 0x094cef46 (0x01baed9c)
  9 0x094cb773 (0x01baf214)
  10 0x094cb5a8 (0x01baf248)
  11 0x094cb42a (0x01baf258)
  12 0x094cb321 (0x01baf290)
  13 0x094ca349 (0x01baf2a4)
  14 0x073b067b (0x01baf370)
  15 0x05b6d4ed (0x01baf384)
  16 0x791421db EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in clr (0x01baf394)
  17 0x79164a2a EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in clr (0x01baf410)
  18 0x79164bcc EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in clr (0x01baf550)
  19 0x79164c01 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in clr (0x01baf56c)
  20 0x79164c21 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in clr (0x01baf584)
  21 0x7922ce82 EntryPoint+0x37591() in clr (0x01baf6e8)
  22 0x7922cf90 EntryPoint+0x3769f() in clr (0x01baf950)
  23 0x7922cda4 EntryPoint+0x374b3() in clr (0x01bafe34)
  24 0x7922d199 EntryPoint+0x378a8() in clr (0x01bafe88)
  25 0x7922d09a EntryPoint+0x377a9() in clr (0x01bafed4)
  26 0x792aaf00 EntryPoint+0xb560f() in clr (0x01baff0c)
  27 0x603b55ab EntryPoint+0x2032() in mscoreei (0x01baff18)
  28 0x79007f16 EntryPoint+0x50c1() in mscoree (0x01baff28)
  29 0x79004de3 EntryPoint+0x1f8e() in mscoree (0x01baff48)
  30 0x7bc567f7 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in ntdll (0x01baff5c)
  31 0x7bc56a50 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in ntdll (0x01baffec)
0x7b010be6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff in kernelbase: subl    $4,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (43 modules)
PE    1a0000-  1ca000   Deferred        zlib1
PE    400000- 1992000   Deferred        swift to-do list
PE   2550000- 29b6000   Deferred        ole32
PE   8800000- 8ca5000   Deferred        comctl32
PE   9170000- 93c7000   Deferred        gdiplus
PE  603b0000-60416000   Export          mscoreei
PE  60930000-60940000   Deferred        nlssorting
PE  61740000-61832000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  62e80000-62fb1000   Deferred        wbemprox
PE  62fc0000-631d3000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  63440000-6347d000   Deferred        wmiutils
PE  63480000-6349b000   Deferred        version
PE  63bc0000-63c04000   Deferred        shcore
PE  64a40000-64b29000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  64ec0000-652b9000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE  66240000-66288000   Deferred        bcrypt
PE  68500000-68640000   Deferred        combase
PE  69fa0000-69fa9000   Deferred        wminet_utils
PE  6a280000-6a4cd000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  6bc00000-6bc99000   Deferred        sechost
PE  6bcc0000-6be60000   Deferred        setupapi
PE  6c9c0000-6cf59000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  6e8c0000-6eb79000   Deferred        crypt32
PE  6ed00000-6f389000   Deferred        user32
PE  6fa80000-6fc82000   Deferred        dbghelp
PE  6fe40000-6fedb000   Deferred        rsaenh
PE  70b40000-70df9000   Deferred        ucrtbase
PE  71200000-71251000   Deferred        imm32
PE  79000000-7904a000   Export          mscoree
PE  79060000-7911e000   Deferred        msvcr100_clr0400
PE  79140000-797af000   Export          clr
PE  79810000-79870000   Deferred        clrjit
PE  7a820000-7a824000   Deferred        opengl32
PE  7b000000-7b348000   Dwarf           kernelbase
PE  7b600000-7b929000   Deferred        kernel32
PE  7bc00000-7bea9000   Dwarf           ntdll
PE  f5fb0000-f5fb6000   Deferred        ws2_32
PE  f5ff0000-f5ffb000   Deferred        winspool
PE  f6040000-f6044000   Deferred        wined3d
PE  f61d0000-f61d4000   Deferred        dxgi
PE  f6310000-f6314000   Deferred        iphlpapi
PE  f6e10000-f76e2000   Deferred        shell32
PE  f7820000-f7824000   Deferred        winex11
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000020 uninstaller.exe
    00000024    0
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0
    00000040    0
    0000004c    0
    00000064    0
    00000084    0
    0000009c    0
    000000a8    0
    000000bc    0
    000000dc    0
    000000e0    0
00000044 svchost.exe
    00000048    0
    00000054    0
    00000058    0
0000005c winedevice.exe
    00000060    0
    00000068    0
    0000006c    0
    00000070    0
00000074 plugplay.exe
    00000078    0
    00000088    0
    0000008c    0
    00000090    0
    000000b0    0
0000007c explorer.exe
    00000080    0
    000000c8    0
    000000cc    0
00000094 winedevice.exe
    00000098    0
    000000a0    0
    000000a4    0
    000000ac    0
    000000b8    0
000000d4 rpcss.exe
    000000d8    0
    000000e4    0
    000000e8    0
    000000ec    0
    000000f0    0
    000000f4    0
0000010c (D) C:\users\marco\Local Settings\Application Data\Swift To-Do List\Swift To-Do List.exe
    00000110    0 <==
    00000114    0
    00000118    2
    00000128    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.19.0-35-generic
```

Comment: It was at the end of the log, I thought that was enough, I report it at the beginning of the post for convenience.

Comment: I added the output of the 'lsb_release -a' and 'uname -a' commands.

Comment: Did you try installing dotnet 4.0 with Winetricks?

Comment: Yes, I tried to install dotnet 4.0 with winetricks, also tried to download dotnet 4.0 as separate installer. And tried to install wine mono, none of this worked, giving variations in installation failure errors for which perhaps I should open specific posts.

Comment: Sorry, my internet has been off the entire day. You can also try install the software with PlayOnLinux. I have had success with POL with some software that refused to install directly with wine. But note that some Windows stuff is just too complex and won't install any way at all such as Garmin Basecamp 425 onwards.

Comment: I had no success with PlayOnLinux, but I was able to get it started with Crossover, which unfortunately costs an annual fee.  If only I understood what Crossover did different from Wine I could try to replicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try a 64 bit wineprefix. My current wineprefix is a 64 bit with dotnet 4.0 and the demo version installs without a problem. It does say something about starting dotnet during the installation, but I clicked okay and the installation continued. See the images below. I was able to start and run the program on my system which is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. My wine version is wine-8.0

[image: quick_start_guide]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man, your test helped me to solve the problem.

Actually I had a version of wine which, even if the most recent one available on the store, was not the most recent one that could be installed on Ubuntu 22.04.

It was a bit of a pain to reinstall everything but I was able to install the program I was interested in.